# Codeship CI returns unexplainable Composer error

Tags: php, symfony, continuous-integration, composer-php

Running a CI build on [codeship.io](http://www.codeship.io) returns into an unexplainable error. The last lines of the debug text is:

```
[..]
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets handling the          post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

[ErrorException]                                          
Undefined property: Composer\Script\CommandEvent::$getIO
```

The codeship documentation doesn't say much about deploying/building a Symfony application. It seems like it is impossible to create the `bootstrap.php.cache` file.

**EDIT:**

I'm using Symfony `2.4.3-DEV`, composer is unable to finish the `post-install-cmd` scripts, so it looks like composer has no i/o interface at Codeship. Adding `composer self-update` to the install script at Codeship does result in the same error.

The codeship configuration is:

```
# Set php version through phpenv. 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5 available
phpenv local 5.4

# Install dependencies through Composer
composer selfupdate
composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader
```

Comment: What's your symfony version and post the config_dev.yml

Comment: You should probably mail the codeship guys. They usually respond pretty fast and they might offer a solution or at least a hint

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified PHP in the `Select your technology to prepopulate basic commands` field ? What are your Setup Commands ?

Mine are :

```
phpenv local 5.5
composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

Comment: I've added the codeship config, but it is the default configuration that is added when I select PHP as technology

Comment: But you can edit the default config and add whatever you want, no ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I've been playing with the config and the same error keeps occuring. Adding `--no-scripts` does result in a succesful completion of `composer install` but then obviously running the PHPUnit tests is impossible.